# Why cannot be stored my Array?

Tags: arrays, excel, vba, udf

I have this code in vba, trying to fill an dynamic array with data extracted from a text file but appears me an error

> "subscripts out of range".

I did try to make this with non-zero based arrays but I receive the same error.

**Module VBA**

```
option explicit
Sub FromFileToExcel()
Dim Delimiter As String
Dim TextFile As Integer
Dim validRow As Integer
validRow = 0
Dim x As Integer
Dim i As Integer
Dim FilePath As String
Dim FileContent As String
Dim LineArray() As String
Dim DataArray() As String
FilePath = "C:\Users\Jlopez25\Desktop\bertha\INVPLANT.prn"
TextFile = FreeFile
Open FilePath For Input As TextFile
FileContent = Input(LOF(TextFile), TextFile)
Close TextFile
LineArray() = Split(FileContent, vbCrLf)
For x = LBound(LineArray) To UBound(LineArray)
If validateData(LineArray(x)) Then
ReDim Preserve DataArray(validRow, 3) 'here occours the mistake
DataArray(validRow, 1) = Left(LineArray(i), 8)
DataArray(validRow, 2) = Mid(LineArray(i), 9, 7)
DataArray(validRow, 3) = Mid(LineArray(i), 18, 2)
validRow = validRow + 1
End If
Next x

Range("a1").Resize(UBound(DataArray, 1), UBound(DataArray, 2)).Value = DataArray()

End Sub
```

**UDF**

```
Public Function validateData(Data As String) As Boolean
If InStr(1, Left(Data, 8), ":", vbTextCompare) = 0 And _
Len(Replace(Left(Data, 8), " ", "", , , vbTextCompare)) > 7 And _
Left(Data, 1) <> "_" Then
validateData = True
Else
validateData = False
End If
End Function
```

this are some lines of the text file that I want to separate into DataArray() :

```
abc:c
page: 1

____________________________
site    Location        item
MX823JXIA1B38C08 01
MX823JXIA9B06C58 02
MX823JXIA9B12C76 03
```

Comment: You can only use Redim Preserve to change the *last* dimension of an array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> `ReDim Preserve DataArray(validRow, 3) 'here occours the mistake`

that is because you cannot `Redim Preserve` an Array by changing its first dimension, but only the last dimension. You might want to write your own custom function to achieve this special `Redim`.

But from your code, I can see that it was possible to calculate the size of the array in a first loop, then do the work in another loop. although it is slow (depends on the complexity of the `validateData` function), but it easy to achieve. Consider this:

```
Dim arSize as Integer
For x = LBound(LineArray) To UBound(LineArray)
    If validateData(LineArray(x)) Then arsize = arSize + 1
Next
ReDim DataArray(arSize, 1 to 3) 'dimension the array

'And now do the calculation loop
For x = LBound(LineArray) To UBound(LineArray)
    If validateData(LineArray(x)) Then
    DataArray(validRow, 1) = Left(LineArray(i), 8)
    DataArray(validRow, 2) = Mid(LineArray(i), 9, 7)
    DataArray(validRow, 3) = Mid(LineArray(i), 18, 2)
    validRow = validRow + 1
End If
```

Comment: it is true A.S.H :/ "Resizing with Preserve. If you use Preserve, you can resize only the last dimension of the array. For every other dimension, you must specify the bound of the existing array." according to MSDN ,. you answer is right anyway jeje, thank you, I will work in a UDF for this

Comment: @JoeJoe you can envisage to calculate the dimension of the array first, redim it at once, than do the calculation. If your application is not time-critical, although this is slow, but it should work and it is an easy and quick fix. Try it as in my edited answer ;)

Answer (score 0):

If you size `DataArray` to match the size of the input file then you don't really need to keep resizing it.  It likely doesn't matter that part of it remains empty...

```
Option Explicit

Sub FromFileToExcel()
    Dim Delimiter As String

    Dim validRow As Integer
    validRow = 0
    Dim x As Integer
    Dim i As Integer
    Dim FilePath As String
    Dim LineArray() As String
    Dim DataArray() As String

    FilePath = "C:\Users\Jlopez25\Desktop\bertha\INVPLANT.prn"

    LineArray() = Split(FileContent(FilePath), vbCrLf)

    ReDim DataArray(1 To UBound(LineArray) + 1, 1 To 3)

    For x = LBound(LineArray) To UBound(LineArray)

        If validateData(LineArray(x)) Then
            validRow = validRow + 1
            DataArray(validRow, 1) = Left(LineArray(i), 8)
            DataArray(validRow, 2) = Mid(LineArray(i), 9, 7)
            DataArray(validRow, 3) = Mid(LineArray(i), 18, 2)
        End If

    Next x

    Range("a1").Resize(UBound(DataArray, 1), UBound(DataArray, 2)).Value = DataArray()

End Sub

Public Function validateData(Data As String) As Boolean
    If InStr(1, Left(Data, 8), ":", vbTextCompare) = 0 And _
        Len(Replace(Left(Data, 8), " ", "", , , vbTextCompare)) > 7 And _
        Left(Data, 1) <> "_" Then
        validateData = True
    Else
        validateData = False
    End If
End Function

Function FileContent(sPath As String) As String
    Dim TextFile As Integer
    TextFile = FreeFile
    Open FilePath For Input As TextFile
    FileContent = Input(LOF(TextFile), TextFile)
    Close TextFile
End Function
```